# Not understanding how to upload my code with external librarires

Tags: github, libraries

I'm working on a music visualizer script in python. I'm using an audio library called aubio. If I upload my code on a website like Github how can I make the script available for everyone? Do I have to include the library in the code? Do I have just to explain in the readme that the library is required or adding directly the source code would be a solution?

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice here is to document the dependency: what it is, if a certain version is required, if it only works on some systems, how to install it if there is extra configuration. The benefit of open-source, or at least sharing the code, is that if setting up aubio is confusing for someone, they can tell you and you can add more detail to your README.

Including the library in your code, which I take to mean checking your dependency's source code into your repo, should be avoided. Many projects create a file called `.gitignore` that ignores such directories (`deps/`, `node_modules/`) by default. Checking aubio in will lock you out of updates to the codebase, encourage folks to edit that code when they shouldn't, and add unnecessary size to your repo.